# Service Fabric actor model handling multiple actor types

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor, actor-model

I am using Service Fabric as my microservice framework. I am using a stateless service because we are using an external database. I have 2 types of users: one is a CSR (Customer representative) and another is the user itself. How do I arrange my Actor services to solve this problem?

CSR has very little functionality. But the Customer is a big piece of the whole puzzle.
Let's say CustomerActor needs to update it's own address. The same operation can be done by CSRActor as well.

Is it suggested to create 2 different Actors, CSRActor and CustomerActor, and then CSRActor operates on the customer actor for any operation. Or Customer can be a separate service, and both types of actors call CustomerService.
Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

[Actor polymorphism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-polymorphism) is supported. You can have an Actor type that inherits from another Actor type.

Something like this:

```
public abstract class CustomerBase : Actor, ICustomer
{ }

[ActorService(Name = "Customer")]
public class Customer : CustomerBase, ICustomer
{ }

[ActorService(Name = "Csra")]
public class Csra : CustomerBase, ICsra
{ }
```

That will save you the overhead of doing 2 calls to answer one question.

Comment: I think the code `Csra : CustomerBase, ICustomer` should be `Csra : CustomerBase, ICsra`, where `ICsra` might implement `ICustomer` because the question suggests that they will have at some point different operations

Comment: Thanks @LoekD This is little off topic, but in my example where there is a customer interacting with other services (payment, invoice etc) what are the advantages of having Customer as an actor vs a reliable service?